# Javascript inherited object overwrites other inherited object

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

Can someone please explain what the correct way is to have multiple objects inherit from a parent and have their own prototype functions? I'm trying to do this in nodeJS.

I have these files.

ParserA_file

```
var ParentParser = require('ParentParser_file');

module.exports = ParserA;
ParserA.prototype = Object.create(ParentParser.prototype);
ParserA.prototype.constructor = ParserA;
ParserA.prototype = ParentParser.prototype;

function ParserA(controller, file) {
    ParentParser.call(this, controller, file);
    this.controller.log('init --- INIT \'parser_A\' parser');
    this.date_regex = /([0-9]{1,2})?([A-Z]{3})?([0-9]{2})? ?([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/;
    this.date_regex_numeric = /(([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}))? ?([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})?/;
    this.date_format = 'DDMMMYY HH:mm';
}

ParserA.prototype.startParse = function() {
  console.log('Starting parse for A');  
}
```

ParserB_file

```
var ParentParser = require('ParentParser_file');

module.exports = ParserB;
ParserB.prototype = Object.create(ParentParser.prototype);
ParserB.prototype.constructor = ParserB;
ParserB.prototype = ParentParser.prototype;

function ParserB(controller, file) {
    ParentParser.call(this, controller, file);
    this.controller.log('init --- INIT \'parser_B\' parser');
    this.date_regex = /([0-9]{1,2})?([A-Z]{3})?([0-9]{2})? ?([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/;
    this.date_regex_numeric = /(([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}))? ?([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})?/;
    this.date_format = 'DDMMMYY HH:mm';
}

ParserB.prototype.startParse = function() {
  console.log('Starting parse for B');  
}
```

ParentParser_file

```
ParentParser = function(controller, file) {

    if (!controller) {
        throw (new Error('Tried to create a Parser without a controller. Failing now'));
        return;
    }
    if (!file ) {
        throw (new Error('Tried to create a Parser without a file. Failing now'));
        return;
    }
    this.controller = null;
    this.file = null;

}

module.exports = ParentParser;
```

Now I require them both in my node app

```
var ParserA = require('ParserA_file');
var ParserB = require('ParserB_file');
```

Now, when only one parser is loaded the there is no problem, however, loading them both into my node app and starting parser A

```
var parser = new ParserA(this, file);
parser.startParse()
```

returns

```
init --- INIT 'parser_B' parser'
```

Now for the question, how come ParserB's function `startParse` overwrites the `startParse` from ParserA?

Comment: You assign something to `ParserA.prototype`, and then 2 lines later you assign something *else* to `ParserA.prototype`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because they refer to the same prototype object.

```
ParserA.prototype = ParentParser.prototype;
...
ParserB.prototype = ParentParser.prototype;
ParserA.prototype === ParserB.prototype; // true
```

Remove those two lines (which are overwriting the two lines above them anyway) and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Yup. `ParserA.prototype = Object.create(ParentParser.prototype)` already takes care of adding ParentParser's prototype to ParserA's prototype chain.

Comment: Yes, totally right. Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees. That single line did indeed overwrite the other function. Thanks for the pointer.